# Why does Ordered[A] use a compare method instead of reusing compareTo?

Tags: java, scala, programming-languages, interop, comparison

```
trait Ordered[A] extends java.lang.Comparable[A] {
  def compare(that: A): Int
  def <  (that: A): Boolean = (this compare that) <  0
  def >  (that: A): Boolean = (this compare that) >  0
  def <= (that: A): Boolean = (this compare that) <= 0
  def >= (that: A): Boolean = (this compare that) >= 0
  def compareTo(that: A): Int = compare(that)
}
```

Isn't it a bit useless to have both `compare` and `compareTo`?
What is the huge benefit I'm missing here?

If they had just used `compareTo` I could just had replaced `Comparable` with `Ordered` in my code and be done.

Comment: Does ordered predated comparable? That's odd but at least one implementation invokes the other.

Comment: Nomenclature. It's just Scala's way of being different from big Java.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think it's a historic accident. `Ordered` originally did not inherit from `Comparable`. Once it did, the `compare` name was already established.

Comment: A good reason at the beginning for not inheriting from Comparable would be that originally Scala targeted both JVM and MSIL.

Comment: @Jean: But this doesn't pose a big problem, it is the same with scala.Serializable.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the authors of the Scala libraries just prefer the name compare().